# Generic virtual methods - override method ignored

Tags: c#, generics, mono

I'm trying to make a generic virtual method, but for some reason the override is ignored. An identical non-generic implementation works as expected

Here's the essentials of the code in question:

EDIT: Turns out this might be more obscure than I anticipated - I'm using Unity/Mono, and it's not working there, but it is working in VS

EDIT: Adding things to make it a complete program

```
public interface IController
{
    void Set<T>() where T : class, IController;
    void Set(Type t);
}

public abstract class Controller : IController
{
    public IController parent;
    public virtual void Set<T>() where T : class, IController
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType());
        parent.Set<T>();
    }
    public virtual void Set(Type t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType());
        parent.Set(t);
    }
}

public class ControllerGroup : Controller
{
    public override void Set<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
    public override void Set(Type t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IController obj = new ControllerGroup();
        obj.Set<Controller>();
    }
}
```

EDIT/Clarification: The output should be "Success!" but instead it is "ControllerGroup", then of course a null reference exception

I'm accessing this method through an `IController` interface, which declares both these methods. Unsure if that affects anything

Anyway, the problem is that the override for the generic method is just ignored. The console output shows that the object type is indeed `ControllerGroup`, but this seems to have no effect.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but could you show the code calling the methods?

Comment: How is parent defined and where does it come from?

Comment: I seem to be missing the point, are you saying youare calling set on ControllerGroup and it is not calling Set in Controller? Because that is the expected behaviour

Comment: Sorry - forgot to add the `parent` member. It's there now

Leon: I'm calling `Set<T>` on a `ControllerGroup` object, but the method defined in `Controller` is being called, and not the override in `ControllerGroup`

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Without that, we're really just guessing.

Comment: Can you also add the code of `IController`?

Comment: On a side note, it is great to see a new user post such a fascinating question!

Comment: It is working fine here.  `Success!` is the execution result.  I have only copy+paste the complete example you provided.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It prints `Success!` for me. .Net4.0, Win7, Vs2012

Comment: Using LINQPad - code works as expected!

Comment: Hmm... I opened up VS and did just that, and yeah it worked.. but it's still not working in Unity/Mono. Perhaps that's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It seems that in Unity/Mono, if an interface has a generic method, the 'callvirt' opcode doesn't properly traverse the hierarchy and just takes the first method it finds. So doing this fixed the problem:

```
void IController.Set<T>()
{
    Set<T>();
}
```

Since, within the method, `this` is a class and not an interface, the bug is worked-around.